# How to effectively make limitations on querying API when your front-end uses it

Tags: architecture, api-design

Let's assume that I have a website with a map showing sensors in different locations.

My website provides API for developers with limitations - 1000 requests/day are for free and if you want more you have to pay $0.0008/request. Verification is done using a credit card.

However, this map that I have uses the same API for querying data. How can I make the API capable of distinguishing these two things? I want users to be able to see sensors data on my map on my website but I don't want other developers to steal this data without using the proper API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to see that you realize that every API on the Internet is a *public API*, and therefore can be abused, given sufficient time to discover its weaknesses.

I suppose a solution could include some of the following ideas.  Sadly, each of the following ideas has a weakness, but a combination of them could adequately cover your requirements.  You may never be able to absolutely guarantee the solution, but you could get very close.

Idea: Track behavior.  Is it easy to recognize the "normal" behavior of a map calling the API?  For example, does it invoke the API only once per minute, or many times per second?  If the normal, map-caused frequency is low, then you could consider higher frequencies to be from developers, rather than map users.

Idea: Track users.  Are users of your website's map required to login?  If so, you could track each user's API calls, and look for numbers that are too high for normal map usage.

Idea: Track each map display.  Each display of a map in a browser window is assigned a unique ID, which is included by the web server in the generated HTML/JavaScript of the web page.  The ID is then sent back with each API request from that displayed map.  In the API server, if the ID is not in the list of those for currently-displayed maps, then the API request is rejected.  This concept is similar to a "[nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)", so I'll call it a *map-nonce*.  A developer who directly calls the API would not have a valid map-nonce, so they cannot masquerade as a map.  And, even if they have a valid map-nonce from another browser or user, it would not be valid for their particular session.  If you implement this, you would have to track the map-nonce's that are active.  After a while, a map-nonce should expire.  When the user logs out, the map-nonce's for that session are expired.  If a map makes an API request, and the request is rejected due to its map-nonce, then the map should re-display, which will cause it to get a new map-nonce from the server.

Idea: Obfuscate.  Put the map and the API on different domains.  Make the map's API different from the developer's API (perhaps *JSON* versus *querystring*).  Don't (publicly) document the map's API.  Only include essential data for the map in the map's API.  Change the map's API at intervals, to trip-up any abusing developers.  As map users have a brain that filters nonsense visual data, you could include bogus data in your map API -- If carefully done, the map users won't mind.

So, by identifying users and map displays, and then considering their API behavior, you should be able to reasonably determine if someone is abusing your API.  Of course, you can bet that someone is going to find a way to hack this, so you should keep statistics, and remember to engage your cerebrum and eyeballs at regular intervals.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If I may ask additional question: Do you know any service which is working like this? I wonder if this is common business model?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a API gaeway like APIGEE then you can choose to apply a policy based on source ip. If source IP for the request is your server (website) then do not apply any limitation policy else apply the limitation policy.

Comment: Thanks, but I think they're too expensive for my project.

Answer (score 1):

I realise you've already accepted an answer but I want to just throw some other things into the mix.

First of all, you are not actually dealing with two scenarios if you have free and paid tiers - you're still catering to developers and you need to track their usage. The difference is simply the number of requests. You only have two scenarios if you allow public (anonymous) access, and if you allow public access you aren't reliably tracking usage regardless of how many tricky tracking techniques you try to add in to the mix.

You should start by ensuring that all of your API consumers (developers) are registered and have to authenticate to your API (look at OAuth 2.0, and only move away from that if you have very good reason to do so).

Tracking by IP is unreliable for a number of reasons. First it can be spoofed, so someone can basically inject an arbitrary IP address in each request so it never looks like it's coming from the same place. Second, people behind any kind of firewall (e.g. within an organisation) may all look like they're using the same IP address - this may or may not be relevant based on your target market, but I'm just saying.

So you're best approach, as suggested by Virgo_The_Perfectionist, is to use an API gateway that can do this for you. You should be looking for something that has:

- a developer portal (preferably supporting both developer self-registration and some kind of payment mechanism / monetisation feature)
- the ability to set up plans that dictate tiers and pricing based on usage
- OAuth 2.0 support for authentication
- SLA policies that can do things like rate limiting, throttling and so on.

You can certainly "roll your own" API gateway but you'll be reinventing the wheel and it may not be worth it financially or effort-wise: depends on how many developers and API calls you're servicing overall. Many gateways offer free trials so you can get started with no financial hit, and then you're probably looking at upwards of $50 per month for the lower plans, and more for higher numbers of developers and API calls.

What you'll also get with a commercial API gateway is metrics and reports so you can actually visualise who's using what and how, which can be invaluable if you're refining and evolving your product.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm thinking rather about 'reinventing the wheel' because of the high pricing plans that those companies offer. IMO it's not so hard to do that, you have to just handle the registration of developers, count their requests, attach some kind of payment mechanism and you're good, right?
BTW Is OAuth 2.0 a 'must have'? I thought about passing API tokens in a parameter of GET request.

Comment: There's a few parts to answer so this might span a few comments. I'm not sure what your volumes are or what your tech stack looks like so it's hard to say what would be suitable but there are free, open source API gateways available that could probably do what you need. [Kong](https://getkong.org) runs in NGINX and has lots of plugins around authentication, security, rate limiting etc. I don't see anything for monetisation but you could potentially write your own plugin for that. [Tyk](https://tyk.io) has community editions available that are free, and runs in Vagrant, Docker, RHEL and Ubuntu.

Comment: OAuth 2.0 is certainly not a must have, but it's well established and there's plenty of support. It's actually an _authorisation_ framework, not an authentication framework (OpenID Connect adds authentication semantics over the top of OAuth 2.0) and is intended for using 3rd party authorisation to access protected resources. If your developers are using credentials unique to your site/service then a custom token-based approach would be fine. OAuth 2.0 comes in handy if you want to support users signing in with Facebook, Google, etc. or the credentials apply across a network of sites.